# Не отображается псевдоэлемент. Подскажите!

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Хочу сделать картинку до input. Не получается. Подскажите...

```css
input {
  width: 27%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px 40px 0 20px;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
 }
  
  input::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 background-image: url(../img/name-bg.png);
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" class="input-name">
```

Comment: для input псевдоэлементы не работают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Псевдоэлементы нельзя применить к элементам, которые ничего не содержат. `input`, `img`в том числе.